# show parent component when all the child content is loaded angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a parent component having 4 child components, in that child component, I am populating a variable and showing that variable in its HTML.

How will I show the whole parent component only if all the child components content is loaded?

Every child component has a get method.

**parent.html**

```
<child1></child1>
<child2></child2>
<child3></child3>
<child4></child4>
```

**.ts**

```
ABC() {
      getMethod().subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response.data && response.status === "success") {
          this.data = response.data;
        } else {
          throw new Error();
        }
      });
  }
```

the function like this in every child component..right now some children are viewing early and some are viewing late. I want to show my parent component that contains all child when all of my child data is present

Comment: you can use `@Output()` and notify the parent of child existence

Comment: I am using @Output. Emmiting true when i get my data after that in parent html, i am  equating it to a function and passing $event(having value true).function in which i am passing event is in parent component and in that i am asing it to variable. On the basis of that variable i am ading ngIf condition... this is not working as expected

Comment: can you please elaborate on what desired functionality you are trying to achieve? Also would need a little bit of more code to work with.

Comment: I want to show my parent component when all the child components data is present in subscribe method. Each child contains a get returning observable and i am fetching data with subscribe method.

Comment: so you mean that all child elements have observables and you wish to display the parent when the observables of the child elements are resolved?

Comment: yes. i have updated  my question also with more details

Comment: posted the answer check it out

Comment: how did you initialzed @output ?

Comment: sorry mate ill do that hang on

Answer (score 1):

for this if you want you could use event emitters.
Here is an example :

```
@Output()
child1EventEmitter= new EventEmitter;


ChildComp1() {
      getMethod().subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response.data && response.status === "success") {
          this.data = response.data;
          this.child1EventEmitter.emit("child1Loaded");
        } else {
          throw new Error();
        }
      });
  }
```

Now in the parent you could do something like this :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="child1Loaded && child2Loaded && child3Loaded && child4Loaded">
    <child1 (child1EventEmitter)="isDataPresent($event)"></child1>
    <child2 (child2EventEmitter)="isDataPresent($event)"></child2>
    <child3 (child3EventEmitter)="isDataPresent($event)"></child3>
    <child4 (child4EventEmitter)="isDataPresent($event)"></child4>
</ng-container>
```

in the typescript you could do the following:

```
    export class Parent {

        child1Loaded: boolean;

        child2Loaded: boolean;

        child3Loaded: boolean;

        child4Loaded: boolean;


        isDataPresent(event) {
            if(event === "child1Loaded") {
        this.child1Loaded = true;
        }
        //and so on for other children
    }
}
```

something like this should help you achieve what you want.

Comment: if i am assigning child1Loaded: boolean= true;.. then only my components are showing.. i tried with one child only.   <child1 (changes)="anotherMethod($event)"
(child1EventEmitter)="isDataPresent($event)"></child1>

Comment: you are setting the same variable to be true even whn you call 2 different functions. keep 2 variables and then set one of them as true and another as false use ng-container and then try with the same condition as in the above answer. That should definitely work.